# TypeDef Structure Defined in Header

Tags: c, arrays, struct, compiler-errors, typedef

Homework.h

```
#ifdef HOMEWORK_H_
#define HOMEWORK_H_

typedef struct
{
        int IDNumber;
        char FirstName[30];
        char LastName[30];
}Student;

int AddStudent();
#endif
```

GradeFunctions.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Homework.h"

#define MAX 100

int AddStudent()
{
        int i;
        int StuNumber = 0;

        Student store[MAX];

        for(i = 0; i < 0; i++)
        {
                if(Strlen(store[i].FirstName) > 0)
                {
                        if(Strlen(store[i].LastName) > 0)
                        {
                                if(Strlen(store[i].IDNumber) > 0)
                                {
                                        int StuNumber = i;
                                        break;
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
        printf("Please enter the students first name: ");
        scanf("%s", store[StuNumber].FirstName);
        printf("\n");
        printf("Please enter the students last name: ");
        scanf("%s", store[StuNumber].LastName);
        printf("\n");
        printf("Please enter the students ID Number: ");
        scanf("%d", &store[StuNumber].IDNumber);
        printf("\n");
        return 0;
}
```

I keep receiving this error every time I try to compile

```
GradeFunctions.c: In function ‘AddStudent’:
GradeFunctions.c:13:2: error: unknown type name ‘Student’
GradeFunctions.c:17:21: error: request for member ‘FirstName’ in something not a structure or union
GradeFunctions.c:19:22: error: request for member ‘LastName’ in something not a structure or union
GradeFunctions.c:21:23: error: request for member ‘IDNumber’ in something not a structure or union
GradeFunctions.c:30:30: error: request for member ‘FirstName’ in something not a structure or union
GradeFunctions.c:33:30: error: request for member ‘LastName’ in something not a structure or union
GradeFunctions.c:36:31: error: request for member ‘IDNumber’ in something not a structure or union
```

I have spent the last couple of hours trying to find a reason this is happening in my textbook and online but to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Too many nested `if`'s.

Comment: There's no such thing as `Strlen()` in the standard library.

Comment: @KemyLand I think that is the reason for the upper case `S`, because their teacher required it's implementation instead of using the library function. But, the OP should know that `store[i].FirstName[0] != '\0'` would have the same effect that `strlen(store[i].FirstName) == 0` has. And also, many `if`'s nested like that makes it very unpleasant to read your code. Please improve the design to avoid that. Use `continue` for example.

Comment: Please accept the answer instead of modifying your question to reflect the fact that your problem is solved. This question should be closed however, because it's about a typo and not a programming problem.

Comment: @iharob It still had a timer on the allowance to accept the answer and I needed to press onward rather than wait for the timer to allow me. It was an alternative solution until I solved all my problems and looked back here again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#ifdef HOMEWORK_H_
```

should be

```
#ifndef HOMEWORK_H_
  ^^^ Missing n
```

Because of that the contents of the file is not included in the code base.

Comment: #1 reason for which I prefer `#pragma once` every day.

Comment: @KemyLand, funny you say that. Just last week I went through a large code base and added `#pragma once` to every header file, using a script of course.